# How create view or query using three or more databases using Dblink in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I can Create query using one reference database.
but I need to create query using three or more database join using dblink extension.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM public.dblink
('demodbrnd','select RollNo,Name from public.tbl_student') 
AS DATA(RollNo INTEGER,Name CHARACTER VARYING);
```

I want to join three Database in above query

Comment: So what is your problem? Just add the others the same way you did with the first.

Comment: No I ask how to connect three or more databases using dblink option in a query or view.. I have Solution

Comment: `select * from dblink(...) as db1  join dblink(...) as db2 on ... join dblink(...) as db3 on ...`

Comment: Please explain briefly